# Promoted Links list to show most clicked document library tiles

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, promoted-links

I am working with SharePoint online and on a subsite landing page, I am using promoted links list web part to render 8 tiles, one for each document library, when users click on these tiles, they get to the document library page respectively.

So I was wondering if there is a way to automatically update the order of these tiles to show most clicked document library tile first followed by others in a descending order. I am not looking for a manual solution here something like changing the order number in the list itself, rather an automated way to show most clicked first maybe by leveraging JS snippet, not sure.

Can someone assist if its doable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is doable with promoted-links web part. The workaround i can think of is using the search result web part. You can use certain rules to show only wanted document libraries with KQL. A sample query only returns document libraries in a site. Add more rules to limit.

```
path:"https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/" contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary
```

And use the viewslifetime property to sort the document library with the times been viewed.